# View goes behind the notification drawer in android lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I am having an problem only in the lollipop device i am putting the screenshot and explanation as below,

[image]

See in this image you can see that how the view goes behind the notification drawer when keyboard show up and its doing only in this app i have try with the same code for different app and its not happening there.

Do anyone has same problem of any idea what cause might be for this?

Answer (score 1):

In your AndroidManifest.xml try and see if it works `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` for the activity